# how do i use the win key to show GUI (autohotkey)

Tags: autohotkey

i am trying to use the windows key as a hotkey to launch a GUI

what i want to do is when i hold down the windows key the GUI is displayed and when the windows key is realeased the GUI is hidden (also i dont want to block the functionality of the win key)

the code works as expected with any other key other than the win key ( i cant seem to figur out why this is happening )

so in the code below, it works perfectly with the z key, but it only works once with the win key and then the whole script stops working (and after pressing the win key it doesnt even work with the z key

```
#SingleInstance force ;only one instance of this script may run at a time!

global guiName = "win_key"

Gui Color, White
Gui -caption +toolwindow +AlwaysOnTop
Gui font, s15 Bold, Verdana
Gui add, text,cblack TransColor, 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
Gui Show, x490 y1035 , TRANS-WIN     ; y1040  x 490     1010  ; e3e3e3
WinSet TransColor, White, TRANS-WIN
Gui, Cancel

~LWin::Gui, Show, NoActivate, %guiName%
~LWin up::Gui, Cancel

~z::Gui, Show, NoActivate, %guiName%
~z up::Gui, Cancel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it 
what was hapenning was that the gui was working correctly, but when the win key was pressed the task bar was comming on top of the gui and the gui was not visible

so fixed it by bring the gui on top again

```
~lwin::
Gui -caption +toolwindow +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, Show, NoActivate, %guiName%
return
```